# c# asp.net custom server control layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a custom server control comprised of a panel containing 2 images, a text box and a label. I wrote the server control in its own solution, compiled and then imported it to my web app so i can see it in my toolbox and use it.

My issue is i cant format it as i would like -should i inject html tags dynamically?

What i end up with is every child control of panel on the same line.

I am struggling to postions the items where i want them. I want the control to be laid out as below.
[image]

My code for my custom control dll is as follows.
namespace CustomButton

```
{
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:CCButton runat=server></{0}:CCButton>")]
    public class CcButton : CompositeControl
    {
        Panel buttonPnl;
        Image logoImg;
        Image errorImg;
        TextBox mainTextTb;
        Label subTextLbl;

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Controls.Clear();

            //init controls
            buttonPnl=new Panel();
            buttonPnl.Width = Unit.Percentage(25);
            buttonPnl.Height = Unit.Percentage(25);
            buttonPnl.ID = "buttonPnl";

            logoImg = new Image();
            logoImg.ID = "logoImg";

            errorImg = new Image();
            errorImg.ID = "errorImg";

            mainTextTb = new TextBox();
            mainTextTb.ID = "mainTextTb";
            mainTextTb.Text = "changed";
            mainTextTb.Font.Size = 20;


            subTextLbl = new Label();
            subTextLbl.ID = "subTextLbl";
            subTextLbl.Text = "sub text";
            subTextLbl.Font.Size = 12;

            //add controls to parent control
            this.Controls.Add(buttonPnl);
            buttonPnl.Controls.Add(logoImg);
            buttonPnl.Controls.Add(errorImg);
            buttonPnl.Controls.Add(mainTextTb);
            buttonPnl.Controls.Add(subTextLbl);
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            //render controls
            buttonPnl.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

If i could construct the below html dynamically, that would be perfect. I have already writtent the code intot he customer control on setiing various attributes like image url and tb text and label text etc.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlButton" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150">
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" Width="100%" Height="100%">
        <asp:TableRow Width="100%">
            <asp:TableCell><asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell><asp:Image ID="imgError" runat="server"  ImageAlign="Right"/></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow Width="100%">
            <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="tbMainText" runat="server" ontextchanged="tbMainText_TextChanged" Text="Main Text" width="100%"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow Width="100%">
            <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblSubText" runat="server" Text="Label"  style="text-align: right" width="100%"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: The best way to address this is grab the HTML it outputs, and play around with that markup, trying to get to the layout you desire.

Comment: But then what do i do - i suspect there is a way to inject html but not sure how. and is this the best way, seems primitive! Maybe use a table?

Comment: What I'm saying is to reproduce the markup in an HTML file, you can test out your design to find out whether or not it's missing a style.  Then from there, you can update your control accordingly, or look elsewhere for the problem.  I don't have the answer; I'm giving a way to research and resolve the issue.

Comment: Thx, il take a look. I would still prefer to not have to inject html via C# code behind.

Comment: I'm only talking from a debugging perspective... I'm not talking about changing your code.

Comment: Its def missing style, i have basically added the contorls one after one another so there will be no style tags between them.

Comment: @Fearghal What do you mean `there will be no style tags between them`? Based on the code you posted, you are adding a style attribute. Do you know how to use css?

Comment: i mean that with the above code i have no tags inserted that may do the job of laying them out as expected. Im not sure how to best lay out the controls within the panel to achieve desired layout. Im not good at css, no.

Comment: Updated question with desired html if thats the way to go.

Comment: @Fearghal This is not HTML: `<asp:Panel ID="pnlButton" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150">` It's server side markup for Web Forms.

Comment: Sorry, your are right, still, can this be done dydnamically? i think i found a way but not 100% yet

Answer (score 0):

Got it, thx to @Brian Mairns for pointing me in a good troubleshooting direction....

I built it in html then used html injection methods to build the button dymaically in the overridden Render() class

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        //render controls
        //buttonPnl.RenderControl(writer);
        AddAttributesToRender(writer);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div); //table start tag
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Cellpadding, "5");
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Width, "200");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table); //table start tag
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr); //row start tag
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td); // cell start tag
        logoImg.RenderControl(writer); //add logo image
        writer.RenderEndTag(); //cell end tag
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td); //cell start tag
        errorImg.RenderControl(writer); //add error image
        writer.RenderEndTag(); //cell end tag
        writer.RenderEndTag(); //row end tag
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr); //row start tag
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Width, "100%"); //make sure row width is 100% of parent
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Colspan, "2"); //make sure row spans 2 cells
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td); //cell start tag
        mainTextTb.RenderControl(writer); //add main text box
        writer.RenderEndTag(); //cell end tag
        writer.RenderEndTag(); //row end tag
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Align, "right"); //make sure row width is 100% of parent
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr); //row start tag
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Width, "100%"); //make sure row width is 100% of parent
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Colspan, "2"); //make sure row spans 2 cells
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td); //cell start tag
        subTextLbl.RenderControl(writer); //add sub label
        writer.RenderEndTag();//cell end tag
        writer.RenderEndTag(); //row end tag
        writer.RenderEndTag(); //table end tag
        writer.RenderEndTag(); //div end tag
    }
```